# Find identical lines between two csv files and create a Matlab variable with them

Tags: matlab, csv

I am having two CSV files with numeric data.

CSV-1:

```
1 -1 $c=2
5 6 -1 $c=8
6 -1 $c=2
```

CSV-2:

```
6 -1 $c=4
8 9 -1 4 $c=8
5 6 -1 $c=2
1 2 -1 3 $c=1
```

Thus, CSV-1 has 3 lines. CSV-2 has 4 lines.

I need to read these files into MATLAB, find identical lines between them and then save them in an array, like
`X = [6 -1; 5  6 -1]`.

** The dataset which i got is having that $c values at the end of every line which I cannot delete. I need identical series of numbers execpt the the last portion that is the $c value.

Comment: Did you manage to read the csv files into matrices? If not try `csvread`. What does "similar" mean? What are similar rows?

Comment: 'similar' means the similar rows. I haven't tried to use csvread() to read the file into a matrix. But, now I suppose that if the file is read into a metrices then intersect between them would the simplest solution.

Comment: There is a difference between similar and identical.

Comment: Yes. That's true. I have changed the quesion title. Reading the CSV using csvread() or dlmread() and then intersecting the matrices gave me the solution. The solution given by @Divakar also worked.

Comment: I realized the problem to be different as I went through my dataset. I have changed the question.

Comment: So, is the first line of CSV-1 `1 -1 $c=2` or `1 -1 2`?

Comment: The first one: 1 -1 $c=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `file1` and `file2` to be the paths to those CSV files respectively, you can use an approach based on:

1) [`importdata`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)(to import data from csv files)

2) [`strtrim`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html)(to remove trailing whitespaces)

3) [`intersect`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)(to get the common lines)

The final code would look something like this -

```
%// Read in the CSV data as strings into cell arrays with each cell saving
%// one line from the files. Use strtrim to remove trailing whitespaces
csv1_data = strtrim(importdata(file1,'\n'))
csv2_data = strtrim(importdata(file2,'\n'))

%// Use intersect to find the common data (lines) for the desired output
X = intersect(csv2_data,csv1_data,'stable')
```

Verify inputs and result -

```
>> type(file1)

1 -1
5 6 -1 
6 -1 
>> type(file2)

6 -1
8 9 -1 4 
5 6 -1    
1 2 -1 3
>> X
X = 
    '6 -1'
    '5 6 -1'
```

---

If you were looking to separate out those numbers for each identical line, you can add one more line of code there -

```
Xcell = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x),X,'uni',0);
```

Thus, the output would look like this -

```
>> Xcell{1}
ans = 
    '6'    '-1'
>> Xcell{2}
ans = 
    '5'    '6'    '-1'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really worked.
I also need to save it as an array. The variable X in this case is a cell. But I need it in an array like, [6 -1; 5 6 -1]
X(1,1) = 6; X(1,2) = -1; X(2,1) = 5; X(2,2) = 6; X(2,3) = -1;

Comment: @Pramit Don't forget to edit "similar" to "identical" lines in the question, if you meant that!

Comment: @Pramit - MATLAB cannot handle ragged or uneven matrices.  The number of columns need to be the same for all rows.  One way you could get around this is to replace those undefined entries with zero.  Another way is to use a `cell` array where each cell would be a 1D array that defines the columns per row.

Comment: I realized the problem to be different as I went through my dataset. I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the above problem by the following code:

```
fid = fopen('csv-1.csv','r');
C = textscan(fid, repmat('%s',1,50), 'delimiter',' ', 'CollectOutput',true);
C = C{1};
fclose(fid);

for i = 1:length(C(1,:))
    index = find(strcmp(C(:,i),'$c')); %index of $c in every columns
if length(index) > 0
    C(index,i) = cellstr('0'); % masking $c with 0
    C(index,i+1) = cellstr('0'); % masking '=' with 0
    C(index,i+2) = cellstr('0'); % masking value with 0
end
end
C = num2cell( str2double(C)) ; 
C = cell2mat(C);  C(isnan(C)) = 0 ; %replacing all NaN with 0
```

Similarly saving data of csv-2 in D. And finally:

```
identical_lines = length(intersect(C,D,'rows'))
```

But, this code is taking lots of time to execute. Is there any other way to solve this problem quickly.